# How to implement min/max validator in Rails 3?

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the rails way of implementing a min max validator in Rails 3 ?

I have a model, with min_age and max_age attributes.

Age can be in the range of 0..100, but I want also to validate crossing values, I mean that max is greather than or equal to min

```
{:min_age => 0, :max_age => 0} => true
{:min_age => 0, :max_age => 1} => true
{:min_age => 1, :max_age => 0} => false # max < min
{:min_age => 1, :max_age => 101} => false # out of 0..100 range
```

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Check out the ActiveModel::Validations::NumericalityValidator:
[RailsAPI NumericalityValidator](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/NumericalityValidator.html)

spec:

```
it {
  subject.max_age = 10
  subject.min_age = 20
  subject.should be_invalid
  subject.errors[:min_age].should include("must be less than or equal to #{subject.max_age}")
}
```

code:

```
validates :min_age, numericality: { greater_than: 0, less_than_or_equal_to: :max_age }

validates :max_age, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 100 }
```

I don't know if you want to validate presence or not, but you would just add that as another key to your validations, e.g.

```
validates :max_age, numericality: { less_than_or_equal_to: 100 }, presence: true
```

Comment: Note - this worked fine on "create" but on "update" I got a "stack level too deep" error - using valid inputs - which was a beast to find.  No clue this validator was the cause since the error makes no ref to the line of code prior to the loop.

Answer (score 31):

You can also use [inclusion...in](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#inclusion), as in:

```
validates :height, inclusion: { in: 1..3000, message: 'The height must be between 1 and 3000' }
```

Answer (score 12):

```
validates_numericality_of :min_age, greater_than: 0
validates_numericality_of :max_age, less_than_or_equal_to: 100
validates_numericality_of :max_age, greater_than: :min_age
```

You can also use age, like this:

```
validates_numericality_of :age, less_than_or_equal_to: 100, greater_than: 0
```

Comment: min_age 30, max_age 10, will still get trough, but it shouldn't - my third line of code in the question.

Comment: I suggested you use a single age input, rather than min and max. One way to solve is to enforce having a max_age larger than min_age. See my edit. I did not test the code. In any case, you need to have some code to insure that the min age is not larger than the max age.

Comment: I can't use a single attribute, because it is not an age but an age range. I know I need some code to ensure the value crossing, that was my question.

Comment: Did you try the edit I did following your initial comment? see my answer, third line of code

Comment: Now it is the same solution as @rayban has posted, but with a different syntax. But thanks anyway.