# Rails 3: How to validate that A < B where A and B are both model attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to validate that `customer_price >= my_price`. I tried the following:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :my_price
  validates_numericality_of :customer_price, :greater_than_or_equal_to => my_price
  ...
end
```

(`customer_price` is a column in the `Products` table in the database, while `my_price` isn't.)

Here is the result:

```
NameError in ProductsController#index
undefined local variable or method `my_price' for #<Class:0x313b648>
```

What is the right way to do this in Rails 3 ?

Comment: perhaps you just need a colon to make my_price a symbol?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement min/max validator in Rails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416278/how-to-implement-min-max-validator-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create a custom validator:

```
validate :price_is_less_than_total

# other model methods

private

  def price_is_less_than_total
    errors.add(:price, "should be less than total") if price > total
  end
```

Comment: Well this actually the right way to do it but your message is wrong ("should be less than total") and I would use "unless" as it is more obvious here ("unless price < total", or at least "if price >= total", note the ">="). Otherwise this example makes no sense.

Comment: @hurikhan77: Thanks I've fixed this up now.

Comment: @RyanBigg This code will fail if price or total is not provided

Comment: No need for a custom validator, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416278/how-to-implement-min-max-validator-in-rails-3

Answer (score 3):

You need do a specific validate :

```
validate :more_than_my_price

def more_than_my_price
  if self.customer_price >= self.my_price
    errors.add(:customer_price, "Can't be more than my price")
  end
end
```