# Is it possible to set validation checks based on two disparate fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base {
starts_at datetime;
ends_at datetime;
}
```

How do I enforce a check which verifies if ends_at is after starts_at?

Comment: You don't need the {}, nor the ;. Ruby is not javascript

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545102/rails-3-how-to-validate-that-a-b-where-a-and-b-are-both-model-attributes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `validate` macro and pass a custom method.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate :validate_timeline

  protected

    def validate_timeline
      unless ends_at > starts_at
        errors.add(:ends_at, "end date cannot precede start date")
      end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no predefined validations for this.
You can however [perform custom validations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations)

Here, you could do something like this :

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :ends_after_starting

  private
  def ends_after_starting
    if starts_at > ends_at
      errors.add(:ends_at, "can't be before starts_at")
    end
  end
end
```